# Is the way I computed this triple integral correct?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

I had to compute the following triple integral:

---

Let
$$D = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \ | \ 1 \leq x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 4 \ | \ x, y, z \geq 0\}$$
Compute
$$\int_D x \ dx dy dz$$

---

I chose to integrate over x as my outer integral, then y and then z as my inner integral. I deduced the bounds for each variable as such:
$$0 \leq x \leq 2$$
$$\sqrt{1-x^2} \leq y \leq \sqrt{4-x^2}$$
$$\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} \leq z \leq \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$$

Then I split up the integral:
$$\int_0^2 \int_\sqrt{1-x^2}^\sqrt{4-x^2} \int_\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}^\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2} x \ dz \ dy \ dx$$

Is my approach correct? Can I now just normally calculate the integrals from the inside to the outside?

---

Edit:

So I tried to do it with spherical coordinates. However, I get $0$ as a result which cannot be. In the end I got to this triple integral:
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \int_1^2 r \ \sin{\phi} \ \cos{\theta} \ r^2 \sin{\phi} \ dr \ d\phi \ d\theta$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use spherical coordinates ? You're between two spheres: it is perfect !

Comment: Oh I guess you're right. I have to look into how to convert to those again but I'll give it a try.

Comment: It's wrong: enough to see, that for $x \in [0,2]$ expression $1-x^2$ will not be positive under root.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I see. I will try your suggestion

Comment: As you are integrating over the region between spheres of radius $1$ and $2$ in first quadrant, either use spherical coordinates or if you are using cartesian or cylindrical, it is easy to just do it for region in first quadrant bound by each sphere and subtract.

Comment: So I tried doing it with spherical coordinates but I got zero... could be that I just made some calculation mistake. I added my attempt to the original question.

Comment: @Kajice. Write addition for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me note, that on $OXY$ you should have
$$\left(\int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}+\int\limits_{1}^{2}\int\limits_{0}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\right)dydx$$
Also, you need appropriate corrections for $z$. Can you manage it?

**Addition**

As I see your attempts, then let me write first integral fully
$$\left(\int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\int\limits_{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}+\int\limits_{1}^{2}\int\limits_{0}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\int\limits_{0}^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}\right)xdzdydx$$
and for [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) $x=r\sin\phi \cos\theta, y=r\sin\phi \sin\theta, z=r\cos\theta$ with $r \geqslant 0, \theta \in [0, 2\pi],  \phi \in [0, \pi]$ and with Jakobian $J=r^2 \sin{\phi}$ we should have
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_1^2 r^2 \ \sin{\phi} \cdot r\sin\phi \cos\theta \ dr \ d\phi \ d\theta$$

Comment: I see, so why are the outer two integrals going from zero to 2/pi and not to 2pi and pi respectively? Since you wrote that theta is in [0, 2pi], phi in [0, pi], I would think that those then are exactly our bounds for the integrals.

Comment: Because of $x \gt 0, y \gt 0, z \gt 0$.

Comment: Sorry... I still don't quite understand why we are integrating to pi/2 and not to 2pi and pi respectively.

Comment: Let's look geometrically to angles: $\theta$ "gives" rotate over $OZ$ axis and as we are in quadrant $x,y \gt 0$, then it is only from $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$, not from whole $[0, 2\pi]$, which give full turn. Same with $\phi$: $z\gt 0$ leaves only $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$. We can obtain it also formally from $z\gt 0 \Rightarrow \cos \theta \gt 0$. From conditions $x,y \gt 0$ we obtain $\sin \theta , \sin \phi, \cos \phi \gt 0$.

Comment: Ooooh, now I get it! Thank you, now it makes complete sense to me.

Comment: Glad to be helpful. Feel free to ask if/when need it.

Comment: I get 15pi/16 btw.

Comment: I obtained same.